# Outlook 2010 missing from indexing options

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

When I go to the indexing options, and under "index these locations:", Microsoft Outlook is missing from the included locations.

Things I have tried when searching this site and google.

1. Did a office Repair
2. Enabled the indexing in features of windows.
3. Unchecked windows search restarted and ticked the windows search in features of windows
4. Tried the troubleshoot search and indexing link for email problems; Everything is up to date.

Most post has a dll that is disabled for the indexing service in the features part of windows., but that is normal since outlook index is built in with windows search.

How do I add the Microsoft outlook location icon on this list?  I did come up on post stating that if you uncheck outlook from indexing locations that you will not be able to get that icon back.  Which I am guessing this is the case.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The fix for me was an Office Repair, but since you tried that, look at these other tips... try this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2769651

Comment: Open Microsoft Outlook 2010 and have it running. Now open Indexing Options. Click Modify and check if OL2010 is listed. I tried it in my system and it worked.

Comment: Yes I tried that as well.  Didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've also found that the "Windows Search Email Indexer" Outlook Add-in must be enabled, inside Outlook options.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (OL2010, W7-64). This worked for me:
I removed ALL of the selected locations by unchecking them in the "Change Selected Locations" (Indexing Options > Modify). Make sure the list in the Summary of Selected Locations" is EMPTY. Close Outlook and re-open Outlook again. I then found "Microsoft Outlook" under "Change Selected Locations" listed again. I could add it, together with other locations, and performed a rebuild of the Index (Indexing Options > Advanced- TAB[Index Settings] > Rebuild)

BTW. Like many others, I tried a rebuild of the index, performed an Office repair and followed other suggested actions, such as checking the event viewer for errors with the service, none of those resolved this issues. Some referred to a "Restore Default Locations" button. Would have been great to have, but I did'nt find it.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and it took me a while to notice that outlook is automatically running in safe mode. 
This is caused by installing KB3114409 - it causes Outlook to run in Safe mode, which uses the default settings.
 Your customization is not lost, they just aren't being used when Outlook is in Safe mode.
Microsoft removed the update, so users who haven't installed the December updates yet won't be affected. Users who are affected have two choices to fix this: uninstall KB3114409 or set a registry key to disable Safe mode.

To set the registry key:

1) Open the Registry editor by pressing Windows key + R. Type regedit in the Open: field. Then click Ok.
2) Browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\​Software\​Microsoft\​Office\​14.0\​Outlook\​Security\
3) If any key in the path is missing, you'll need to create it. Right click on the last key, choose New, then Key and type the key name.
4) Right click on Security key and choose New, and then DWORD Value.
5) Type DisableSafeMode, and then press Enter.
6) Right-click on DisableSafeMode, and then click Modify.
7) In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
8) If you have 64bit Windows and 32bit Office, also add DisableSafeMode, Value: 1 to this key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\​SOFTWARE\​Wow6432Node\​Microsoft\​Office\​14.0\​Outlook\​Security\
9) Restart Outlook or reboot the computer.

This is a link to the source.
It has some programs that will fix the problem (I have not tested these programs) if you do not wish to work in the regedit.exe,
It also explains why it happens and the regedit.exe steps to fix it.
[Problem: Outlook will only open in safe mode.](http://www.slipstick.com/problems/outlook-starts-safe-mode/)

Comment: Welcome to superuser your answer while easily followed just having the links does not provide this site with answers and the links can break.again welcome to SU